# How do I use django-allauth with South?

Tags: python, django, django-south, django-allauth

I'm trying to do a data migration using South. I want to migrate information stored in django-allauth's SocialAccount model to my own UserProfile model. However, I'm having trouble importing django-allauth into the data migration file. Here's what I have so far:

```
class Migration(DataMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        "Write your forwards methods here."
        # Note: Don't use "from appname.models import ModelName". 
        # Use orm.ModelName to refer to models in this application,
        # and orm['appname.ModelName'] for models in other applications.
        for user in orm['auth.User'].objects.all():
            import allauth.socialaccount.models
            print dir(user)
            prof = orm.UserProfile(user=user)
            prof.name = "%s %s" % (user.first_name, user.last_name)
            prof.is_ghost = False
            prof.has_facebook = True if len(user.socialaccount_set.all()) > 0 else False

            prof.save()
```

Upon running this, I get:

```
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'socialaccount_set'
```

I inspected the namespace of `user`, and it seems like `socialaccount_set` is not present. However, it is present when I test it in the shell, and I've been using it all over my application. Any thoughts?